# Spring Boot with RabbitMQ failed to initialize

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am implementing a JMS client for a RabbitMQ server and I have the following Spring Boot config class.

```
@Configuration
public class JmsConfig {

    private static String EXCHANGE_NAME = "exchange";

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;


    @Bean
    RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        return new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory);
    }

    @Bean
    Queue queue(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin) {
        return rabbitAdmin.declareQueue();
    }

    @Bean
    FanoutExchange exchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange(EXCHANGE_NAME);
    }

    @Bean
    Binding binding(Queue queue, FanoutExchange exchange) {
        Binding binding = BindingBuilder.bind(queue).to(exchange);
        return binding;
    }
}
```

Highlight that in the RabbitMQ server the exchange already exists but the queue connected to the exchange should be created dinamycally by the client(that's the intention) when I run it.

When I start the client app I get the following stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'queue' defined in class path resource [com/optimusbet/jms/JmsConfig.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue]: Factory method 'queue' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'exchange' must be non-null.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1173) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1067) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:866) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:542) ~[spring-context-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
at com.optimusbet.OptimusbetSportsClientApiApplication.main(OptimusbetSportsClientApiApplication.java:20) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-1.5.1.RELEASE.jar:1.5.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.amqp.core.Queue]: Factory method 'queue' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'exchange' must be non-null.
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.6.RELEASE.jar:4.3.6.RELEASE]
... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'exchange' must be non-null.
```

Any ideas of what's going wrong in the initialization? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like exception thrown at creating queue bean which expect a exchange.

Can you try making this
@Bean
    Queue queue(RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin, FanoutExchange exchange) {
rabbitAdmin.declareExchange(exchange)       
 return rabbitAdmin.declareQueue();
    }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to declare the queue with the admin - and in fact you should never interact with the broker in a bean definition. The context is not fully baked yet.

You just need...

```
@Bean
Queue queue() {
    return new AnonymousQueue();
}
```

... you can't use broker-named queues here.

Also, this is not a "JMS" client, it's a RabbitMQ client.

**EDIT**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So42328067Application {

    private static final String FANOUT = "fanout";

    private static final String QUEUE = "foo";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = SpringApplication.run(So42328067Application.class, args);
        context.getBean(RabbitTemplate.class).convertAndSend(FANOUT, "", "bar");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(QUEUE);
    }

    @Bean
    public FanoutExchange exchange() {
        return new FanoutExchange(FANOUT);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange());
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = QUEUE)
    public void listen(String in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

Comment: I followed your advice Gary and I declare a Queue like this Queue queue() { return new Queue(QUEUE_NAME, false);} but then similar Exception is thrown when I try to set a listener on the channel in the client.   @RabbitListener(queues = { "${jms.queue.name}"})
public void receiveMessage(final Message message) {..   ERROR 18803 --- [cTaskExecutor-1] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
org.springframework.amqp.UncategorizedAmqpException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid configuration: 'exchange' must be non-null.

Comment: Don't put code in comments; as you can see, it's unreadable - edit the question instead. Also, show the full stack trace and your __current__ configuration.

Comment: I edited my answer with a complete working sample. Again, this has nothing to do with JMS.